# Is only Sleep Mode good for my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

I'm a web designer and I haven't gotten any chance to **shut down** my macbook pro often with my busy schedules. When I'm not working (sometimes on weekends), unfortunately I forget to shut down my Mac for 8-10 hours! However, yet I can charge the Mac after its battery shows 15%.

So, is being always in *sleep mode* a weakening it's battery life? and does it hurt the logic board, honestly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had my MacBook Pro for 6 years now and I barely turned it off over that period. Always in sleep mode when not in use.

If you don't have an SSD (I don't) and need to carry it somewhere it's always better to turn it off to be extra safe with the hard drive.

Ultimately, it's your computer and your responsibility so you have to choose what's best in your opinion. This goes for anyone reading this post as well.